# Describing Middle School in european grant application

Tags: application

I completed my PhD in the US, and I am currently writing a grant application for a EU grant.  While I was a graduate student, I worked on a grant that had me in a middle school classroom (8th grade, so 12-13 year old students).

What is the best, short way to describe this in my grant proposal? I don't want to waste a lot of space describing the specific age range of the students, if it can be avoided.  At the same time, I don't know if it will be clear what I mean if I write "8th grade classroom" or "middle school classroom".  Any ideas?

Comment: "I worked on a grant that had me in a middle school classroom" - if I interpret this the same way you mean it, the research/work you did based on the grant had to be partially or completely conducted in a classroom, while working with the 8th graders? In any case, while it is not unambiguous, either, I would strongly prefer "8th grade" over "middle school", given that the concept of "middle school" can be defined arbitrarily depending on the country (and also, doesn't even exist in some places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describe it like you did here: 8th grade, and then in parenthesis put (ages 12-13) to remove any ambiguity. That will only cost you a couple of words, and no one can misunderstand.

To expand on @ORMapper commented, in Sweden middle school would be "mellanstadiet" which is grades 3-5, and the students are aged 9-11. So specify both what the gade was "called" and the age, and avoid descritors like "middle school"that can vary a lot by country.